# Resize Image and Maintain Aspect Ratio

Tags: image, aspect-ratio

Given a height and width. how can i resize the image to contain into my maximum holder for that image but maintaining aspect ratio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use your mathmatics

this will help

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
sx = original_width/destination_width
sy = original_height/destination_height
if sx*original_height > destination_height:
    s = sy
else:
    s = sx
new_width = original_width*s
new_height = original_height*s
```